# Use of Internationalization Properties without using custom label

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning, javascript, lightning-experience

I have created progress bar indicator and the value i.e. 'qualification', 'need analysis' should change according to user profile/language but it should be dynamic, i dont want it from custom label only for language. IAs i am new in lwc can someone help me to achieve this.

html

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-theme_default">
        <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
            <lightning-progress-indicator type="path" current-step={selectedStep}>
                <lightning-progress-step label="Qualification" value="qualification" onclick={selectStepqualification}>
                </lightning-progress-step>
                <lightning-progress-step label="Need Analysis" value="analysis" onclick={selectStepanalysis}>
                </lightning-progress-step>
                <lightning-progress-step label="Proposal" value="proposal" onclick={selectStepproposal}>
                </lightning-progress-step>
                <lightning-progress-step label="Negatiation" value="negatiation" onclick={selectStepnegatiation}>
                </lightning-progress-step>
                <lightning-progress-step label="Closed" value="closed" onclick={selectStepclosed}>
                </lightning-progress-step>
            </lightning-progress-indicator>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-m-vertical_medium">
            <lightning-button label="Next" onclick={nextStep}></lightning-button>
            <lightning-button label="Previous" onclick={previousStep}></lightning-button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

js

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

 export default class pathChange extends LightningElement {

    @track selectedStep ='qualification';

    nextStep()
    {
        var moveToNextStep = this.selectedStep;
        if(this.selectedStep == 'analysis')
        {
            this.selectedStep = 'proposal';
        }
        else if(this.selectedStep == 'proposal')
        {
            this.selectedStep = 'negatiation';
        }
        else if(this.selectedStep == 'negatiation')
        {
            this.selectedStep = 'closed';
        }
        else if(this.selectedStep == 'qualification')
        {
            this.selectedStep = 'analysis';
        }
    }

    previousStep()
    {
        var moveToPreviousStep = this.selectedStep;
        if(this.selectedStep == 'analysis')
        {
            this.selectedStep = 'qualification';
        }
        else if(this.selectedStep == 'closed')
        {
            this.selectedStep = 'negatiation';
        }
        else if(this.selectedStep == 'negatiation')
        {
            this.selectedStep = 'proposal';
        }
        else if(this.selectedStep == 'proposal')
        {
            this.selectedStep = 'analysis';
        }
    }

    selectStepqualification()
    {
        this.selectedStep = 'qualification';
    }
    selectStepanalysis()
    {
        this.selectedStep = 'analysis';
    }
    selectStepproposal()
    {
        this.selectedStep = 'proposal';
    }
    selectStepnegatiation()
    {
        this.selectedStep = 'negatiation';
    }
    selectStepclosed()
    {
        this.selectedStep = 'closed';
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can translate other things, like picklists. Since you appear to be using the Opportunity Stage field, you can translate it, then load the labels with [`getPicklistValues`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-wire-adapters-picklist-values.html) or [`getPicklistValuesByRecordType`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-wire-adapters-picklist-values-record.html). Then, just bind the attribute to a getter.

```
 <lightning-progress-step label={qualificationLabel} ...
```

```
import OPP_STAGE from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.StageName';

...

@wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '000000000000000AAA', fields: [OPP_STAGE]) stageOptions;

get qualificationLabel() {
  if(this.stageOptions.data?.values) {
    return this.stageOptions.data.values.find(
      (stage) => stage.value === 'Qualification'
    ).label;
  }
  return 'Qualification';
}
```

Comment: but this wont change the language according to user login.. for eg a user from Germany has login then he should be able to see in german language

Comment: @ShejalRaut The label will be in the user's setup language, the same as a custom label would be.